# Why is it that if $\alpha$ is a root with minimal polynomial of degree $2^k$ (for some integer $k$), then $\alpha$ is constructible?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

Why would it be true that if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree equal to a power of $2$ then $\alpha$ is constructible?  I came across this fact recently while studying Galois theory on my own, but there was no justification given.

Comment: That is because it's true for degree $2$.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is true. Constructibility requires that $\alpha$ is an element of a field $L$ in a tower
$$\Bbb{Q}=K_0\subset K_1\subset K_2\subset\cdots\subset K_n=L$$
such that $[K_{i+1}:K_i]=2$ for all $i$. But if $\alpha$ is a zero of a quartic with Galois group $S_4$, then there are no intermediate fields between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$, so constructibility is not given. If $\alpha$ belongs to a field $M$ such that $M/\Bbb{Q}$ is **Galois** and of degree $2^\ell$, then $\alpha$ is constructible. The existence of a tower then follows from the properties of $p$-groups.

Comment: Actually, this is not quite true. If a number $\alpha$ is constructible in $\Bbb Q$, then $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ *must be* a power of $2$. But knowing that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ is a power of $2$ is not sufficient to know whether $\alpha$ is constructible.

Answer (score 5):

It is not true for degrees higher than $2^1=2$.  For example, the irreducible equation $x^4-x-1=0$ has no constructible roots.  If you try to solve the equation with radicals you get cube roots which you can't simplify, and you're doomed.

For irreducible quartic equations over the integers the roots can be constructed only if the resolvent cubic has constructible roots,  which means the resolvent cubic has to have a rational root.  This is not true of $x^4-x-1=0$ or in general.  If the equivalence breaks down here, there is no justification for assuming it could repair itself for higher power-of-$2$ degrees.